# Multiple Insert Query in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I had requirement to perform two insert queries in two different tables.

I am using Oracle/Java Combination.

What are the options available in this case?

Comment: hm, SQL using the JDBC API would be one option... What exactly is the problem? What do you use today?

Comment: I had a form. At submit of  form, I need to insert data into two different tables at the same time. Could not understand yr second question....

Comment: Have you ever programmed in Java before?

Comment: Is this is really a dummy question? If yes, kindly tell the solution... and Programming in java for 1.5 yrs.

Comment: Ok. I didn't look into Batch Option in JDBC. If forums feels this is really a basic question, then i regret it..

Comment: You don't necessarily need the batch option. You can simply use the `java.sql.Connection` object you already use and perform a second `insert`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward method is to do two inserts sequentially using the same connection.  Assuming that part of your point is that you want the two inserts to occur in the same transaction, then make sure you have disabled autocommit on the connection, and explicitly commit after the second insert.

Another option would be to write an Oracle stored procedure that does the inserts, and call it from Java with a PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to insert the same data into two separate tables you can use a multitable insert like this:

```
insert all
into table1(a, b)
into table2(a, b)
select 1 a, 2 b from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample from devdaily.

```
package com.devdaily.sqlprocessortests;

import java.sql.*;

public class BasicJDBCDemo
{
  Connection conn;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new BasicJDBCDemo();
  }

  public BasicJDBCDemo()
  {
    try
    {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/coffeebreak";
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
      doTests();
      conn.close();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {System.err.println(ex.getMessage());}
    catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {System.err.println(ex.getMessage());}
    catch (InstantiationException ex) {System.err.println(ex.getMessage());}
    catch (SQLException ex)           {System.err.println(ex.getMessage());}
  }

  private void doTests()
  {
    doSelectTest();

    doInsertTest();  doSelectTest();
    doUpdateTest();  doSelectTest();
    doDeleteTest();  doSelectTest();
  }

  private void doSelectTest()
  {
    System.out.println("[OUTPUT FROM SELECT]");
    String query = "SELECT COF_NAME, PRICE FROM COFFEES";
    try
    {
      Statement st = conn.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
      while (rs.next())
      {
        String s = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
        float n = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
        System.out.println(s + "   " + n);
      }
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
      System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }

  private void doInsertTest()
  {
    System.out.print("\n[Performing INSERT] ... ");
    try
    {
      Statement st = conn.createStatement();
      st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO COFFEES " +
                       "VALUES ('BREAKFAST BLEND', 200, 7.99, 0, 0)");
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
      System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }

  private void doUpdateTest()
  {
    System.out.print("\n[Performing UPDATE] ... ");
    try
    {
      Statement st = conn.createStatement();
      st.executeUpdate("UPDATE COFFEES SET PRICE=4.99 WHERE COF_NAME='BREAKFAST BLEND'");
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
      System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }

  private void doDeleteTest()
  {
    System.out.print("\n[Performing DELETE] ... ");
    try
    {
      Statement st = conn.createStatement();
      st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM COFFEES WHERE COF_NAME='BREAKFAST BLEND'");
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
      System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the sample is with mysql but you should use an oracle driver

Comment: Just a side note: it's good practice to always explicitely state all columns in the INSERT statement to be more robust against changes in the table layout.

Comment: It is good practice to put both inserts in a transaction so that they succeed both or not at all.

Comment: agree...there are a lot of good practices that might apply to the above code...which is just a copy paste from a site for the sake of understanding via concrete simple sample...

Comment: I don't think that copying code from another site, which is not even germane to the specifics of the question, is a very good answer.

Comment: if you read the comments you will see that the person who asked is a newbie and i think the code samples helped him. Your answer despite looks ok is for a person who already read about jdbc.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with StoredProcedures and execute with PreparedStatement in JDBC api. That intern will return you two resultSets , which you can get with a method getMoreResults(). You can then process the resultsets separately.